# Another Model for the API

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I\m using WebAPI in ASP.net MVC 4.5, and I was wondering what is the best practice when dealing the db entities, should I create another Model (you can call it API model or Service model) that deals with the API, pretty much the same way you create a View model to deal with the razor view, or just communicate directly with the db using the EF entities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When it's a public API, I think its better to create extra Web API entities (Models in MVC). You can write a method to map the db entities to Web API entities. When you create extra entities your sure the public side of your API doesn't change when you change database entities.